# Is there a way to image or clone a Windows 8 tablet that runs off eMMC storage?

Tags: windows-8, tablet, imaging, cloning

I am attempting to image or clone Windows 8 tablets that run off eMMC storage. The specific device in use in an Asus Vivotab Smart that runs Windows 8 Core.

Having attempted traditional imaging tools such as Macrium, O&O, etc I am unable to restore Windows 8 to different hardware.

Going off Macrium's forum at http://support.macrium.com/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=5573, it appears it may be a general lack of support for eMMC controllers. I am unsure.

What tools can I use to image the tablet and restore the image to other devices that may include desktops and laptops or tablets?

Comment: Product suggestions are not really on topic here, since its an interesting problem, willing to point you towards Acronis® True Image™ 2014 Premium which has the capability of restoring a True Image archive to different hardware.

Comment: @Ramhound - Not looking for product recommendations. Have tried Acronis and it doesn't work either. I am looking for a solution be it a product or otherwise.

Comment: The only way to image a computer is with software which means a recommending a software solution.  What isn't working with the software you have tried.  Once you create an image restoring the image should be the easy part.

Comment: @Ramhound - The image is created successfully however the message across the applications seem to be consistent i.e. lack of support for the disk layout. My understanding based on forums is that due to the differences in disk layout (not sure what this means), restoring the images won't work - see http://support.macrium.com/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=5673&SearchTerms=flash,drive. Seeing that conventional software solutions aren't working, is there a method of say using Linux tools that may help achieve the same result?

Comment: Most don't care about what disk looks like.  The problem is that Windows cares about what hardware its restored to.  Which is the reason I suggested the version of Acronis I did.  The tool has to support restoring to different hardware.  What version of Acronis did you try?

Comment: @Ramhound - Do they work though with eMMC devices and restore to different hardware?

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey - Did you find a solution?